# WPF List, where you can flip out every row and you get more rows under this row

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, list

i want a list filled with e.g. cars and when i click on one row, some rows with different shops, where you can buy these cars should be shown under the clicked row.

How can i realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a datagrid, you can set the RowDetailsTemplate that will automatically show the details for the selected row. This is a whole dataGrid, look at the RowDetailsTemplate section. It contains another datagrid for the details.

```
            <Data:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SortedContainers}" 
                                       SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                       FrozenColumnCount="0" IsEnabled="True">
            <Data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <Data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Model.Bk_Term}" Header="Terminal" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <Data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Equip Id">
                    <Data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Eqp_Id}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  IsEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </Data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <Data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Customer}" Header="Owner" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <Data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Location}" Header="Location" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <Data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Model.RE059Id}" Header="Id" IsReadOnly="True" />
            </Data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <Data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Data:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding NoteList.AllItems}" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="14" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Visibility="{Binding NoteList.AllItems.Count, Converter={StaticResource RowCountVisibilityConverter}}"
                        RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
                        <Data:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <Data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Notes"  Width="*">
                                <Data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Note}"
                                                    FontSize="10" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                        </TextBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </Data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </Data:DataGrid.Columns>
                    </Data:DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </Data:DataGrid>
```